# how to assign different gin log writer in run time in golang

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm using *gin-gonic* in my golang project. I want to record logs in separate files for each day. So I made a *go ticker* to generate a *log.txt* file every 24 hours. I used channels to access the generated log file. So I use my file generator function in the main function and try to assign it to `gin.DefaultWriter` like this:

```golang
    logChannel := make(chan io.Writer)
    defer close(logChannel)
    go logger.InitLogTimer(logChannel)
    go func() {
        for c := range logChannel {
            gin.DefaultWriter = io.MultiWriter(c, colorable.NewColorableStdout())
        }
    }()
```

My main function is like this if it is useful to know:

```
func main() {

    models.InitDB()

    route := gin.Default()
    route.Static("/assets", "../../view")
    route.LoadHTMLGlob("../../view/html/**/**/*")

    logChannel := make(chan io.Writer)
    defer close(logChannel)
    go logger.InitLogTimer(logChannel)
    go func() {
        for c := range logChannel {
            gin.DefaultWriter = io.MultiWriter(c, colorable.NewColorableStdout())
        }
    }()



    routes.RegisterUserPublicRoutes(route)
    routes.RegisterUserProtectedRoutes(route)

    route.Run(":8080")

}
```

and this is my function that generates log files:

```
func InitLogTimer(write chan io.Writer) {
    generateLogFile(write)
    tick := time.Tick(24 * time.Hour)
    for range tick {
        go generateLogFile(write)
    }
}

func generateLogFile(write chan io.Writer) {
    dest := fmt.Sprintf("../../cmd/main/log/%v", time.Now().UnixMilli())
    if err := os.MkdirAll(dest, os.ModePerm); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error while creating log directory: ", err.Error())
    }
    filename := fmt.Sprintf("%v/%v.txt", dest, time.Now().Format("01_02_2006"))
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error while creating log file: ", err.Error())
    }
    write <- logFile
}
```

But it doesn't work. Because even though the log files are generated, nothing is written on them, and gin still uses just `colorable.NewColorableStdout()`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: with this code you are assigning something to `gin.DefaultWriter`, but are you actually using it? E.g. `router.Use(gin.Logger())`, you need to set the logging middleware

Comment: it could also be a race condition, since access to `gin.DefaultWriter` isn't synchronized. The logger goroutine, assuming that one exists, might not even see the updated values

Comment: Am I right that your gorutine with Gin is up and running 24/7 and you want to implement another goroutine to change the log filename for it?

Comment: @blackgreen I think the race condition you mention is correct because, after a long run, I realized some logs are written. So if in the terminal I see, for example, ten records, in the log file I would have just 3 logs.

Comment: @NikitaPetrov yes, that's correct. I just added the rest of my codes to give you a better view.

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796021/how-can-i-log-in-golang-to-a-file-with-log-rotation

Comment: Thank you, based on that, and with the help of using the third-party library, the logs are written in both terminal and log.txt, but I still have to test it because it doesn't support a log duration of less than one day. But I was hoping I could do that without a third-party library. @blackgreen

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The difference between what you see in the stdout and what you see in the log file could be because of how the errors are handled in your code.
For example, if you use panic(), you'll get a record in the log file, but if you use just c.Error or any other way to handle errors, they will not be written to the log but would be just printed in the stdout output. Here is the test code you can play to figure out how different errors are handled:

```
func main() {
    route := gin.Default()

    logChannel := make(chan io.Writer)
    defer close(logChannel)
    go InitLogTimer(logChannel)
    go func() {
        for c := range logChannel {
            gin.DefaultWriter = io.MultiWriter(c, colorable.NewColorableStdout())
        }
    }()

    route.Use(gin.Logger())
    route.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "pong")
        panic("foo") // Will be in the log and stdout
    })
    route.GET("/ping2", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "pong")
        c.Error(errors.New("Just a normal error")) // Will not be written to the log but you can see it in the stdout
    })
    route.Run(":8080")
}

func InitLogTimer(write chan io.Writer) {
    generateLogFile(write)
    tick := time.Tick(10 * time.Second)
    for range tick {
        go generateLogFile(write)
    }
}

func generateLogFile(write chan io.Writer) {
    dest := fmt.Sprintf("../../cmd/main/log")
    if err := os.MkdirAll(dest, os.ModePerm); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error while creating log directory: ", err.Error())
    }
    filename := fmt.Sprintf("%v/%v_%v.txt", dest, time.Now().Format("01_02_2006"), time.Now().UnixMilli())
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error while creating log file: ", err.Error())
    }
    write <- logFile
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the logs I'm referring to are usually the gin logs, for example, HTTP Get request, HTTP POST request, their status code, and the endpoint called.